# Generate PDF document with multiple layers (OCG)

Tags: c#, .net

What .Net opensource libraries can be used to generate a PDF document with multiple Optional Content Groups?

The main goal is to create a document that has separate layers for text and image schematics. Its intended that the final user is able to hide/view any of the layers on a PDF reader.

Comment: Maybe MigraDoc supports but no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution in this forum post: https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2682&hilit=layers

It is possible to successfully modify PDFsharp ir order to create layers on PDF documents.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf.
I think there is a way to do this with this library.

Edit: I'm sorry didn't read the part about being opensource.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).